# EKS NodeAffinity for Services

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, eks

https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/140_assigning_pods/affinity/

Links like above usually show node affinity for "kind: Pod".

Isn't it possible to use node affinity for "kind: Service" whereby all pods in a service will have a node affinity?

Answer (score 1):

i guess you mean a Deployment because service do not have any pods, and yes, you can use node affinity on a Deployment. you can find it here https://www.howtoforge.com/use-node-affinity-in-kubernetes/